# why am i unable to change the numericInput() value when in the browser?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinydashboard

When i run the following code in RStudio i can change the value of the numericInput() in the Viewer. For example it starts as '5' and i can change it to any value between 0 and 100.

The issue i'm having is when i try running the code in the browser i'm unable to change the value from it's initial value of '5'.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "MY TITLE"),

  dashboardSidebar(

    numericInput("numbers", "nums", 5, min = 0.00, max = 100, 1)

  ), 

  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This must have to do with your browser. I tried out your app in current versions of Google Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Interne Explorer. The appearance of the input widget is not exactly the same in the four browsers. Internet Explorer has the poorest appearance, because there are no up/down arrows to change the number and the keyboard arrows don't work eather. But still you can delete the old number and type in a new number. In terms of functionality all four browsers work fine. So maybe just install a newer version of your preferred browser.

Comment: Yes you're correct, it is browser related although i'm already using IE 11. It's fine though as i prefer using Chrome anyway. I've only been using IE for shiny as it by default uses that.

Comment: @Till you should probably add your comment as a form of answer, so Steve would be able to give you your credit :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works great for me. I published it on Rcloud.
There are small buttons which makes value increase by 1.if you cant see them it may be css issue.

Try these options too.
if (interactive()) {

ui <- fluidPage(
numericInput("numbers", "nums", 5, min = 0.00, max = 100, 1)

numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  verbatimTextOutput("value")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$value <- renderText({ input$obs })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
}[image]